# Verifying credit cards (creditcardcheck) on Payone with Python

Tags: python, payment-gateway, credit-card, payone

I'm trying to verify credit card on **PayOne** (https://www.payone.de/en/).

List of params I've got from `According to 3.4.1 Verifying credit cards (creditcardcheck)` and `3.1.2 Standard parameter` section of documentation PAYONE_Platform_Client_API_EN.pdf (you can request it here https://www.payone.de/en/contact/).

1. I calculate the hash value of (aid, api_version, mid, mode, portalid, responsetype, request, storecarddata) (Python) and pass it to client side.

```py
# build hash on server side: 
import hmac
import hashlib

params = {
    'aid': '123456', 
    'api_version': '3.12', 
    'mid': '123456', 
    'mode': 'test', 
    'portalid': '1234567', 
    'responsetype': 'JSON', 
    'request': 'creditcardcheck', 
    'storecarddata': 'yes'
}
message = ''.join([params[k] for k in sorted(params)])
return hmac.new(b'some-secret-key!', msg=message.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
```

2. and then do JSONP (why here is no CORS and RESTful API?) request to with additional params (**cardcvc2, cardexpiredate, cardpan, cardtype**) and hash that I got from serverside:

> [https://secure.pay1.de/client-api/?aid=123456&api_version=3.10&cardcvc2=123&cardexpiredate=1801&cardpan=012344567890123&cardtype=M&mid=12345&mode=test&portalid=1234567&responsetype=JSON&request=creditcardcheck&storecarddata=yes&hash=c6a8fe28e6d4cc63139aae5eba41bdb74f877f364a444745f4083a22db0f9861247cd4a0dfa82bd42df1ff7724754ea6&callback_method=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished](https://secure.pay1.de/client-api/?aid=123456&api_version=3.10&cardcvc2=123&cardexpiredate=1801&cardpan=012344567890123&cardtype=M&mid=12345&mode=test&portalid=1234567&responsetype=JSON&request=creditcardcheck&storecarddata=yes&hash=c6a8fe28e6d4cc63139aae5eba41bdb74f877f364a444745f4083a22db0f9861247cd4a0dfa82bd42df1ff7724754ea6&callback_method=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished)

3. get result:

> {
>       "customermessage": "An error occured while processing this transaction (wrong parameters).",
>       "errorcode": "2007",
>       "errormessage": "Hash incorrect",
>       "status": "ERROR" }

I'm using python 3.5 and angular2.

What I'm doing wrong here?

## PS:

- you can find example php code [here](https://github.com/fjbender/simple-php-integration), but no python code

## PPS:

The hash method has been chosen in the web interface: https://pmi.pay1.de/merchants/?navi=portal&rc=1 (`Method hash calculation*: SHA2-384 (recommended method)`)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is call endpoint without `api_version` parameter:

```
# build hash on server side: 
import hmac
import hashlib

params = {
    'aid': '123456', 
#    'api_version': '3.12', 
    'mid': '123456', 
    'mode': 'test', 
    'portalid': '1234567', 
    'responsetype': 'JSON', 
    'request': 'creditcardcheck', 
    'storecarddata': 'yes'
}
message = ''.join([params[k] for k in sorted(params)])
return hmac.new(b'some-secret-key!', msg=message.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()
```

## PS

In the same time `api_version` is noted as required parameter at section `3.1.2 Standard parameter` and as parameter that should be hashed at section `3.1.4 Calculation of the HASH value`. So it looks like type in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Per default, the payone merchant accounts use md5 instead of sha384

```
# build hash on server side: 
import hmac
import md5
import hashlib

params = {
        'request': 'creditcardcheck', 
        'responsetype': 'JSON',       
        'mode': 'test',               
        'mid': '12345',                                
        'aid': '54321',                                
        'portalid': '2222222',                         
        'encoding': 'UTF-8',                           
        'storecarddata': 'yes', 
}
message = ''.join([params[k] for k in sorted(params)])
print message

m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(message)
m.update("secretkey")
print m.hexdigest()
```

This outputs:

```
54321UTF-812345test2222222creditcardcheckJSONyes
a435bff18234ec02a2dffa4d4850a08f
```

Then, open the URL and make sure all parameters except credit card params (and callback method) passed in the URL are in the hash as well. In this example it's:

https://secure.pay1.de/client-api/?aid=54321&cardcvc2=123&cardexpiredate=1801&cardpan=4111111111111111&cardtype=V&mid=12345&mode=test&portalid=2222222&responsetype=JSON&encoding=UTF-8&request=creditcardcheck&storecarddata=yes&hash=a435bff18234ec02a2dffa4d4850a08f

Comment: yes, thanks! i've forgotten to added that in web interface of `payone` (https://pmi.pay1.de/merchants/?navi=portal&rc=1) I have chosen `Method hash calculation*: SHA2-384 (recommended method)`